# Nativescript Inspector not showing elements

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When running `tns debug ios --watch` the Nativescript inspector is attached to the application, but when I am going to the `Elements tab` to see the structure of the application I am not getting anything. Or maybe should I look somewhere else?

I have the nativescript sample "groceries".

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the nativescript community, the Native inspector is not able to render this on the current version.

Comment: Is being worked on I believe for the January release.